# c3p0 not closing inactive connectionbs

Tags: java, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

I am struggling these days with my application that is using struts and hibernate with oracle. To have efficient pooling we have also implemented c3p0.
On some busy day the application dies(doesn't allow users login), when I look at the db I find the inactive connections spiked up abnormally(beyond 5 seconds).Please look at my c3p0 configuration:

Here are my observation:
1. I doubt if c3p0 is being effective ever. I have seen several times the inactive connections >5 sec beyond 300 connections, which is weird and should not happen with current set up of c3p0(c3p0.timeout=300 ms).
2. I don't see any issue with the application loading the login page, only the users are forbidden to login.

Thank You in advance.

**UPDATE** My c3p0 configuration:

```
connection.provider_class:org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connect‌​ions.internal
c3p0.max_size=100
c3p0.min_size=5
c3p0.timeout=300
c3p0.max_statements=0
c3p0.idle_test_period=120
c3p0.acquire_increment=1
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100
```

Comment: did you post any configuration? you might also want to look at your JVM stack traces when your application dies. Hibernate's `c3p0.timeout` refers to how long Connections can sit idle in the pool. Since you say problems occur when your application is busy, that's probably not your issue. Plus, the unit of Hibernate's `c3p0.timeout` / c3p0's `maxIdleTime` is seconds, not msecs, so if you've set it to 300, that means 5 minutes.

Comment: Please find my attached configuration:

Comment: Apologies for the missed attachments , please have a look : connection.provider_class:org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.interna
  c3p0.max_size=100
                c3p0.min_size=5  
                c3p0.timeout=300
         c3p0.max_statements=0
  c3p0.idle_test_period=120             c3p0.acquire_increment=1
  hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100
. Am I missing any parameter that I should be bothered for.
Let me know if any further details required,
Thank You in advance.

Comment: At this point i don't see any chances to `optimize` connections...where is `hibernate.c3p0.min_size`/`max_size`?.And why you use `org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connect‌​ions.internal` instead of `org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider`? I think problem is here.

Comment: Shall I use org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider instead of org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0Connecti‌​onProvider(currently used in my application), that's what you are saying?I am using hibernate-c3p0-4.2.1.Final , c3p0-0.9.5.2 and mchange-commons-java-0.2.11 for c3p0.